# Multiply IF in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    [TesterName]
    ,[MTDate]
    ,[Login]    
    ,[TesterStatus]
    ,[TesterState]     
    ,[Workweek]
FROM 
    [Montester_Preprod].[dbo].[pub_MontesterData]
WHERE 
    SiteName LIKE '%HVC%' 
    AND TesterTypeName = 'CMT' 
    AND 
        (    TesterName NOT LIKE '%263%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%371%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%201%'  
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%521%'
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%588%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%299%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%284%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%493%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%386%')
```

That returns this data:

```
TesterName  MTDate  Login   TesterStatus    TesterState Workweek
CMT0062 2017-02-22 00:15:00.000 czma    1   3   201708
CMT0062 2017-02-22 00:30:00.000 czma    1   3   201708
CMT0062 2017-02-22 00:45:00.000 czma    1   3   201708
CMT0062 2017-02-22 01:00:00.000 czma    1   3   201708
CMT0062 2017-02-22 01:15:00.000 czma    1   3   201708
CMT0062 2017-02-22 01:30:00.000 czma    1   2   201708
CMT0062 2017-02-22 01:45:00.000 czma    1   7   201708
CMT0327G1   2017-03-28 11:00:00.000 hadargox    1   7   201713
CMT0289G1   2017-03-28 11:00:00.000 oaharoni    1   7   201713
CMT0748G1   2017-03-28 11:00:00.000 vfarcas 1   7   201713
CMT0628G1   2017-03-28 11:00:00.000 obarhum 2   7   201713
CMT0534G1   2017-03-28 11:00:00.000     1   1   201713
CMT0062G1   2017-03-28 11:00:00.000 hadargox    1   7   201713
```

What I'm trying to retrieve and failed is when "MTDate" (Search on the same full date  + "testername" are equal ("testername" should be without "G1" at the end, for example CMT0062 = CMT0062(G1)) if both searches are true check tester status if both of them are 1 "print" 1 to the new column if not take "TesterStatus from the row without the "G1" at testerName.

For each "MTDate" I have two identical dates call one for CMT0371 and one for CMT0371G1 for example.

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: Is that the full query?  I don't see any of the logic you are talking about at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Yes but not all results.. I will try to explain...
I have Master and slave computers for each cell. each cell called CMTxxxx, Master name is always 7 caracters with CMT+4 numbers, Slave name is the same as tester name plus "G1".
What im trying to retrieve is the combine status of both Master & slave together, and if Master is "1" at status and Slave is "1" too print it as only 1 from master data (date must be the same too).
I have to time calls for each tester, one is master call and second is the slave.

Comment: Look at your four cases: If CMTxxxx = 1 and CMTxxxxG1 = 1, return the value of CMTxxxx (always 1): If CMTxxxx = 0, or CMTxxxxG1 = 0, return the value of CMTxxxx. So, in all cases, just return the value in CMTxxxx, and you will return the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the truth table for your query, and you will see something that isn't obvious, but simplifies your logic.

- IF CMTxxxx = 1 AND CMTxxxxG1 = 1 and MTDate columns match, return 1 (CMTxxxx)
- IF CMTxxxx = 1 AND CMTxxxxG1 = 0 and MTDate columns match, return CMTxxxx
- IF CMTxxxx = 0 AND CMTxxxxG1 = 1 and MTDate columns match, return CMTxxxx
- IF CMTxxxx = 0 AND CMTxxxxG1 = 0 and MTDate columns match, return CMTxxxx

If, *when the MTDate columns also match*, you always return the value in CMTxxxx, you will always return the correct value - no comparison needed.

To get all of the rows that should be shown for your case, my query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    [TesterName]
    ,[MTDate]
    ,[Login]    
    ,[TesterStatus]
    ,[TesterState]     
    ,[Workweek]
FROM 
    [Montester_Preprod].[dbo].[pub_MontesterData] pmd
WHERE 
    SiteName LIKE '%HVC%' 
    AND TesterTypeName = 'CMT' 
    AND 
        (    TesterName NOT LIKE '%263%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%371%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%201%'  
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%521%'
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%588%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%299%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%284%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%493%' 
         AND TesterName NOT LIKE '%386%'
        )
    AND NOT (
        pmd.TesterName Like '%G1'
        AND EXISTS (
             SELECT *
             FROM [Montester_Preprod].[dbo].[pub_MontesterData] pm2
             WHERE pm2.TesterName = Left(pmd.TesterName, Len(pmd.TesterName)-2))
                  AND pm2.MTDate = pmd.MTDate
            )
```

Comment: it should be under time limitation.
 •IF CMTxxxx = 1 AND CMTxxxxG1 = 1, return 1 (which is the value of CMTxxxx)  ---> on specific time.

Comment: Edited my answer to address your comment, @Avi22. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the next error:
"The multi-part identifier "pm2.MTDate" could not be bound"
any idea why?